# Missing symbols when using Clang with libc++ on CentOS 7 (no C++ ABI lib?)

Tags: c++, centos7, clang++, libc++

The following packages were installed from repositories on CentOS 7.6:

- clang-3.4.2-9.el7.x86_64
- libcxx-3.8.0-3.el7.x86_64
- libcxx-devel-3.8.0-3.el7.x86_64

Trying to build a simple C++ program:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ junk.cpp
```

This results in a bunch of linker errors, an example is:

```
/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libc++.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
```

AFAIK, this seems to be a problem of missing C++ ABI library, but I can't figure out how to install one that would provide the needed symbols.  I could probably build one from source, but would like to stick with what's available from trustworthy repositories.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I can build the program just fine if `-stdlib=libc++` is omitted, in which case libstdc++ is used.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `-lc++abi` manually. This problem is fixed in modern installations, but the Linux packages aren't modern. Consider using apt.llvm.org

Comment: The problem is that `libc++abi` is not on the system. :(  And I can't figure out where to get it.  There may be other libraries that provide the needed ABI, but what are they and where do I get them?

Comment: BTW, thank you for mentioning apt.llvm.org, but I'm on CentOS and don't have the freedom to tweak it much, otherwise I would have just built libc++abi from source.  I also realize there are ways to force deb/ubuntu packages onto an rpm-based system, but again that's not an option.